# How can I disable the Launcher for Medieval 2: Total War?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, medieval-2-total-war

Medieval 2: Total War has a launcher that has always been of questionable utility, but now is a complete annoyance since the update site is offline, and it pops up a dialog box to tell me this.  **How can I disable the launcher and go straight to the game?**  I'm using the game from Steam if it makes a difference.

Comment: have you seen this: http://forums.totalwar.org/vb/showthread.php?70892-Command-line-switches

Comment: @ColinD Looked at it but didn't see anything that helped.  It looks like great information though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Medieval 2 directory and you should see Launcher.exe and Medieval2.exe. If you open the second the game should start bypassing the launcher -just create a shortcut to desktop of that file for next games-.

If you are running it under Steam, just backup the original Launcher.exe file and rename Medieval2.exe to Launcher.exe, which is the file name Steam will launch.

Source: I did it in the past.